# How to invoke a method from combo box event

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to invoke a method from combo box selected change event
with lambda expression but I am stuck with following error

**TypeError: () takes no arguments (1 given)**

I think I have passed 1 argument as per the method definition, could somebody please help me where I am wrong

or any other combobox selected change event code will be great help!

please note  my code

```
self.boxWidget[boxName].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda:invoke_Setting_Group(self))

def invoke_My_method1(self):    
    print "expand another window"
```

I am trying to pass the first class object to the second python script file for variable value assigning easeness.I tried to use this combox event change code without lambda then I noticed that this method is getting called automatically so I used lambda to prevent this automatic method calling

Sorry I am not having the knowledge on lambda expression usage; here I used only to prevent the automatic method execution. Without lambda expression I noticed my combo box function starts automatically, I did not understand why it happens so?

I am using TKinter python 2.6

More Detailed Code of above:

```
#Main_GUI_Class.py
##----------------------
import sys

class App():  

    def __init__ (self,master,geometry=None,root=None):    
        try:
           self.master=master                  
           if not root:
              self.root=Tkinter.Toplevel(master) 

    def initUI(self):
        try:                      
            self.master.title("GUI")        
            menubar = Menu(self.master)
            self.root.config(menu=menubar)    
            fileMenu.add_command(label='Open')                     
            submenu_ncss.add_command(label='Model Setting',command=lambda:Combo_Expand_Script.Call_Model_Setting(self))   

##----------------------

def main():
    r = Tkinter.Tk()    
    r.withdraw()
    r.title("GUI Sample")
    r.wm_iconbitmap(Pic1)
    v = App(r)
    r.mainloop()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

##Combo_Expand_Script.py
##-----------------------

import sys
import Tkinter

import Main_GUI_Class

def Call_Model_Setting(self):
    try:    
        self.PopUpWin = Toplevel(bg='#54596d',height=500, width=365)
        self.PopUpWin.title("POP UP SETTING")

        #Combo Boxs in Pop Up                      
        boxNameGroup="boxSetting"                  
        boxPlaceY=0    
        for Y in range(4):                      
          boxName=boxNameGroup+str(Y)
          if Y == 0:
              boxPlaceY=50
          else:
              boxPlaceY=boxPlaceY+40
          self.box_value = StringVar()

          self.boxWidget[boxName] = ttk.Combobox(self.PopUpWin, height=1, width=20)             

          if Y== 0:
               self.boxWidget[boxName]['values'] = ('A', 'B')
               self.boxWidget[boxName].current(1)
          if Y== 1:
               self.boxWidget[boxName]['values'] = ('X', 'Y')               
               self.boxWidget[boxName].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda:invoke_Setting_Group(self))
          self.boxWidget[boxName].place(x=180, y = boxPlaceY)

       #Buttons in Pop Up
        self.btnApply = tk.Button(self.PopUpWin,width=10, height=1,text="Apply",relief=FLAT,bg=btn_Bg_Color,command=lambda: treeDataTransfer(self,0))
        self.btnApply.pack()          
        self.btnApply.place(x=75, y = 460)                  
        self.btnCancel = tk.Button(self.PopUpWin,width=10, height=1,text="Cancel",relief=FLAT,command=lambda: deleteTreeNodes(self))
        self.btnCancel.pack()          
        self.btnCancel.place(x=170, y = 460)
    except IOError:
       print "Error: data error"

def invoke_Setting_Group(self):#, event=None
    try:    
        #self.boxName.current(0)
        self.boxWidget["boxSetting3"].current(0)
        self.PopUpWin['width']=1050
        self.PopUpWin['height']=700
        self.btnApply.place(x=500, y = 550)
        self.btnCancel.place(x=600, y = 550)        

        self.txtWidget={}  

        lsttxtSetting = ['1', '2','3 ','4','5 ','6','7','8','9','10']                         
        for t in range(10):                  
              txtName=txtNameGroupTS+str(t)
              if t == 0:
                  txtPlaceY=120
              else:
                  txtPlaceY=txtPlaceY+30

              self.txtWidget[txtName] = Text(self.groupSettingFrame,height=1, width=10,borderwidth = 2)
              self.txtWidget[txtName].insert(INSERT, lsttxtSetting[t])
              self.txtWidget[txtName].pack()                      
              self.txtWidget[txtName].place(x=200, y = txtPlaceY)

    except IOError:
       print "Error: Group Settings Popup error"      

def turbDataTransferBind(self):

    for P in range(0,3):
        boxName="boxSetting"+str(X)
        dataSettingbox=self.lstTurb[X]+" "+self.boxWidget[boxName].get()
        self.root_node_Setting = self.tree.insert( self.root_node_ChildSetting["ChildSettingNode"], 'end', text=dataSettingbox, open=True) 

def treeDataTransfer(self,dlgTurbFlag):    
    self.treeDataTransferBind()
    print "data tranfer sucess"
def deleteTreeNodes(self):
    print "delete nodes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command=` and `bind` expect function name - without `()` and arguments - so in place of

If you use

```
.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", invoke_Setting_Group(self) )
```

then you use result from `invoke_Setting_Group(self)` as second argument in `.bind()`. This way you could dynamicly generate function used as argument in `bind`

---

```
TypeError: () takes no arguments (1 given)
```

This means you have function `function()` but python run it as `function(arg1)`

You run `lambda:invoke_Setting_Group(self)` but python expects `lambda arg1:self.invoke_Setting_Group(self)`

You could create function with extra argument

```
def invoke_My_method1(self, event):    
    print "expand another window"
    print "event:", event, event.widget, event.x, event.y
```

And then you could use it

```
.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:invoke_Setting_Group(self, event))
```

---

**BTW:** it looks strange - you have class `App()` but in second file you use only functions instead of some class too.

Comment: It is a very good answer, let me try with this. I wanted to separate function as different script file since my functions are too lengthy and wanted to transfer the values from functions script file to main class widgets. When keep two different class I met with many dependency errors! and I am confused to pass the class objects  to transfer the values each other. Is there any other way doing other than what I am trying, please suggest